# Loop through array, return True if next int is equal to current

Tags: java, arrays

elementIsUsed(int curYPos, int curXPos, int nextYPos, int nextXPos)

if curYPos == nextYPos && curXPos == nextXPos in array[][], return true.

How do I iterate over a (long) array[][] to reach my solution?

I've tried iterating using a for loop but this gives me an error.

```
for(index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        if(array[curYPos][curXPos] == array[nextYPos][nextXPos])
        {
            isUsed = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what "your solution" is meant to be. What did _you_ try?

Comment: The question is much too vague to be answered.  Please edit it to provide a sample input, an expected output, a solution that you tried, and actual output / errors.

Comment: What error are you getting?